# Null exception when try to display data from viewmodel in view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to display data in my view using a ViewModel however I am getting null exceptions when doing so and I am not sure what the issue is. Basically I have a user, who's data I wish to display in a profile layout in my view, as well as data from different tables all in the same profile view.

ViewModel Code:

```
public int DonatorID { get; set; }
public string DonatorName { get; set; }
public string DonatorSurname { get; set; }
public string DonatorEmail { get; set; }
public int ContactNo { get; set; }
public int UserID { get; set; }

public string DonatorRank { get; set; }
public string RankIcon { get; set; }
public int XpAmount { get; set; }
public int TokenBalance { get; set; }

public int PaymentID { get; set; }
public string CardNo { get; set; }
public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }
public int ExpirationYear { get; set; }
public int CVV { get; set; }
public int Zip { get; set; }
public string CardType { get; set; }
public int PaymentDonatorID { get; set; }

public int NpoID { get; set; }
public string NpoName { get; set; }
public double Longitude { get; set; }
public double Latitude { get; set; }
```

Controller Code:

```
id = 1;
//Disable lazy loading
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

//Add data to the dynamic object
var DynamicProfileDetail = db.tblDonator.Where(zz => zz.user_id == id).Include(yy => yy.tblUser).Include(xx => xx.tblDonator_Rank).FirstOrDefault();

DonatorUserViewModel ProfileDetails = new DonatorUserViewModel();
//Set profile details values
ProfileDetails.DonatorName = DynamicProfileDetail.donator_name;
ProfileDetails.DonatorSurname = DynamicProfileDetail.donator_surname;
ProfileDetails.DonatorEmail = DynamicProfileDetail.tblUser.email;
ProfileDetails.ContactNo = Convert.ToInt32(DynamicProfileDetail.donator_contact_no);

//Set other information
ProfileDetails.XpAmount = DynamicProfileDetail.xp_amount;
ProfileDetails.DonatorRank = DynamicProfileDetail.tblDonator_Rank.description;
ProfileDetails.RankIcon = DynamicProfileDetail.tblDonator_Rank.rank_icon;
ProfileDetails.TokenBalance = DynamicProfileDetail.donator_token_balance;

//Payment details section
int DonatorID = DynamicProfileDetail.donator_id;
var DynamicPaymentDetails = db.tblDonator_Payment_Details.Where(gg => gg.donator_id == DonatorID).Include(ff => ff.tblCard_Type).FirstOrDefault();

DonatorUserViewModel PaymentDetails = new DonatorUserViewModel();

//Set payment detail values
PaymentDetails.CardNo = DynamicPaymentDetails.donator_card_no;
PaymentDetails.ExpirationMonth = DynamicPaymentDetails.expiration_month;
PaymentDetails.ExpirationYear = DynamicPaymentDetails.expiration_year;
PaymentDetails.CVV = DynamicPaymentDetails.cvv;
PaymentDetails.Zip = DynamicPaymentDetails.zip_code;
PaymentDetails.CardType = DynamicPaymentDetails.tblCard_Type.description;

//Map marker section
var DynamicMapMarkers = db.tblNpo;

DonatorUserViewModel MapMarkers = new DonatorUserViewModel();

//Set map marker values
foreach (var item in DynamicMapMarkers)
{
   MapMarkers.NpoID = item.npo_id;
   MapMarkers.NpoName = item.npo_name;
   MapMarkers.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.longitude);
   MapMarkers.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.latitude);

   MapMarkerList.Add(MapMarkers);
}

//ViewBags to display the relevant info
ViewBag.MapMarkerList = MapMarkerList;

return View();
```

My logic in the code above is that I am setting the values from my database to the objects in the ViewModel and then would be able to display it in my view.

View Code:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.DonatorUserViewModel

<h2>View/Edit your Details:</h2>
<ul>
   <li>First Name: @Model.DonatorName</li>
   <li>Surname: @Model.DonatorSurname</li>
   <li>Contact Number: @Model.ContactNo</li>
   <li>Email Address: @Model.DonatorEmail</li>
</ul>
```

Sorry for the amount of code in the question (particulary the viewmodel and controller sections) I just need to show that there are a lot of different objects from different database tables.

Now back to my issue, I am getting a null exception in my view for `<li>First Name: @Model.DonatorName</li>` and I'm assuming for the rest of them as well. I have a feeling there is something wrong with the way I am trying to use my viewmodel, as I am used to doing it using lists and then looping through that list in the view, however I am not sure how to do it now that I am only displaying essentially one line from the database tables instead of all the lines. Anyway any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what `FirstOrDefault()` is, for your `DynamicProfileDetail` object? And have you gotten any exception with details?

Comment: @DavidLiang As far as I understand the `FirstOrDefault()` is so that it gets the first row with the correct id, this is the exception as it appears in VS: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' if i view the details of the exception it displays a table with various info.

Comment: There is a difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`. Later would return NULL if the filter results in no result. That's what that OrDefault means.

Comment: I just tried `First()` and I am getting the same error. I used breakpoints to step through the controller code and it is setting the values correctly, its just in the view where it's returning nulls.

Comment: Your view has a declared model type (DonatorUserViewModel), but your controller logic isn't sending a model to the view, it's just using ViewBag. Why are you using ViewBag? That just complicates everything. Have you seen the proper way to pass a model into the View? How to pass a model to a view is covered in any basic ASP.NET MVC tutorial, like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller).

Comment: @mason is right. It looks like you spent lots of efforts building up the view model but at the end you just throw it away. And yes, since you're building a view model and plan to return it back to the view, why then use another thing (ViewBag) to do so at the same time?

Comment: Apparently not lol, I usually use lists and send that to the view, I see what I have done wrong, thanks for the help ill keep you guys posted.

Comment: Alright I have actually sent data to the view now and all is working as intended thanks a lot @mason and DavidLiang

Comment: I'd still caution you to ditch using ViewBag. ViewBag is almost never a good solution.

Comment: yeah no I have ditched the ViewBag